# Get the next task from queue using fair slot policy

Tags: php, mysql, math, task

On our service users can add different tasks which are executed as soon as a slot is available.
All tasks are stored in a mysql table. The table looks like

```
user_id | task   | status         | created_at | started_at 
int     | string | pending,active | datetime   | datetime
```

We're currently using a fifo strategy but since the amount of tasks is increasing and we don't want to add a limit on how much tasks a user can add, we want to add a fair slot policy to it. Normally a task runs between 30 to 75 minutes before it's finished. It also can be less or more.

I created a set of sample data:

Example data:

```
158 total tasks
144 pending tasks 
 14 running tasks
 15 tasks can run at the same time

 # of pending tasks for each user    
 user 1 => 28 tasks
 user 2 => 76 tasks
 user 3 =>  5 tasks 
 user 4 => 22 tasks
 user 5 =>  3 tasks

 # of active tasks for each user
 user 1 =>  5 tasks
 user 2 =>  0 tasks
 user 3 =>  2 tasks 
 user 4 =>  4 tasks
 user 5 =>  3 tasks
```

My approach is to
-first: divide the number of pending tasks for each user by the amount of total pending tasks (pending_tasks_of_user_x / pending_tasks).
-second: Then divide the active tasks to the amount of tasks which can run at the same time (active_tasks_of_user_x / concurrent_tasks).

But now I don't know how to proceed. If my approach is totally wrong, i'm open for it.

To access the database i'm using php.

EDIT:

As fair I define that the user doesn't has to wait, till all other tasks of the other users are completed. For example user 2 has 76 tasks and user 1 has 28 tasks. Now user 5 adds 3 tasks. I don't want that user 5 has to wait till all tasks of user 1 and 2 have to be executed first before the tasks of user 5 get executed. More like user 2 can run 8 tasks at once user 1 4 and user 5 can run 2, or sth similar. If more users than concurrent tasks are available it should shrink accordingly and some have to wait.

Comment: You haven't said what you consider 'fair'. Is it: The more tasks you submit the more slots you get? Or the opposite? There's something to say for both.

Comment: There's something called [Fair-share scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair-share_scheduling). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware totally forgot that. Sorry for that. Edited the post

Comment: I guess I'm looking for sth similar to Fair-share scheduling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the  [Fair-share scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair-share_scheduling) is a good approach in this case.

Divide the total number of available task slots by the total number of users that have pending tasks.

15 / 5 = 3

So each user can now run 3 tasks at once.

This means users with few tasks will be done quickly and users with many tasks have to wait longer.

If another user appears the available tasks will be

15 / 6 = 2.5

Of course you cannot run half a task, but that can be solved in the actual queuing algorithm.

I think you could implement this in PHP. I don't think it is my place to code this for you.

The algorithm should be something like this:

1. A task slot comes free and is looking for a new task to execute.
2. Find the user with the fewest running tasks.
3. Find the oldest pending task of that user.
4. If the user doesn't have any pending tasks, remove the user from consideration and start again at point 2.
5. Run the pending task.

That's all you need to do to implement this.